# R caret package: data partition into training / test sets before trainControl?

Tags: r, r-caret

I see a lot of R codes where a full dataset is first split into a training set and a test set:

```
library(caret)
library(klaR)

# load the iris dataset
data(iris)

# define a 80%/20% train/test split of the dataset
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p=0.8, list=FALSE)
data_train <- iris[trainIndex,]
data_test <- iris[-trainIndex,]
```

In a second time, a partition method is defined such as repeated k-fold cross validation:

```
train_control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3)
```

Then a model is trained using the training set:

```
my_model <- train(Species~., data=data_train, trControl=train_control, method="nb")
```

Finally, predictions are performed on the test set:

```
pred_results <- predict(my_model, newdata=data_test)
```

When using specifically a (repeated) k-fold cross validation method, it seems to me that the training (n=k-1 folds ) and the test (n=1 fold) sets are already inherently defined.

In this case why adding an extra layer of partition by splitting first the full dataset into 80% training and 20% test sets? Is it necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In chapter 2.2 from Introduction to statistical learning, available [here](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/)

> In general, we do not really care how well the method works training
>   on the training data. Rather, we are interested in the accuracy of the
>   predictions that we obtain when we apply our method to previously
>   unseen test data

Read the whole chapter, including bias / variance trade off.

tldr; You need to test your trained algorithm on unseen data to see how well it performs. If you include your test data in the training (10-fold cv or not), your algorithm has seen these cases. You will be too confident with your predictions.

Comment: Thanks phiver ! Is it not the point with cross validation methods: one partition is left out to be used as a test set (i.e. unseen set)?

Comment: No cv averages across the 10 folds and should make your model more stable. 1 partition is left out for the first fold, but is included in the other 9 folds. All data has will be seen 9 times out of 10. Hence the need for an extra unseen test set outside the cv.

Comment: I understand. Thanks !

Comment: Or maybe it is something specific to the caret package? I am confused. The `train` function of the caret package fits the model and returns accuracy metrics to assess the efficiency of the models. How does it measure these metrics? It should have used a test set generated internally by the `trainControl` function?

Comment: train returns accuracy metrics from training the model (seen data), not from test. It gives you an idea, but not how it will perform on unseen data.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-validation gives a proxy of the out-of-sample error you will obtain on your fully unseen test set. Things to put extra attention are the average of the scores as well as their distribution. If the behaviour is similar in all testing splits you can be confident on the score given by the CV.

Comment: I understand. Thanks !